# Unmounted hard drive times out ejecting or mounting

Tags: hard-drive, macos, disk-utility, external-disk, mount

I have a Drobo connected via Firewire to my MBP which is causing me some issues.  Here is the diskutil info:

```
Device Identifier:        disk2s2
   Device Node:              /dev/disk2s2
   Whole:                    No
   Part of Whole:            disk2
   Device / Media Name:      MacDrobo

   Volume Name:              Mac Drobo

   Mounted:                  No

   File System Personality:  HFS+
   Type (Bundle):            hfs
   Name (User Visible):      Mac OS Extended
   Journal:                  Unknown (not mounted)
   Owners:                   Disabled

   Partition Type:           Apple_HFS
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 FireWire
   SMART Status:             Not Supported
   Volume UUID:              A97C9EAF-E18F-3BE3-80CD-8A8C6FB6E8E7
   Disk / Partition UUID:    3776B4B3-8530-495E-A413-AFB0A221281B

   Total Size:               2.2 TB (2200000000000 Bytes) (exactly 4296875000 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:        0 B (0 Bytes) (exactly 0 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (not mounted)

   Device Location:          External
   Removable Media:          No
```

It is not mounted but it is still very active in reading and writing...I can hear it thrashing about.  When I try to eject or mount I get time out errors, when I try to run verifyVolume, I get a bit more of a complex error.

```
MacTravis:~ travis$ Sudo diskutil eject disk2
  Volume timed out while waiting to eject

MacTravis:~ travis$ Sudo diskutil mount ReadOnly disk2
  Volume on disk2 timed out waiting to mount

MacTravis:~ travis$ Sudo diskutil verifyVolume disk2s2
  Started file system verification on disk2s2 Mac Drobo
  Verifying file system
  File system check exit code is 8
  Error: -69845: File system verify or repair failed
  Underlying error: 8: POSIX reports: Exec format error
```

I assume my computer is doing something in the background as when I unplug the drive it stops being active, and becomes active again when I plug it back in.  I have tried using Disk Utility to see what is up but if the drive is plugged in then DU never loads completely, if its open then I plug in the drive nothing shows up.  Is there any way to see what is going on with the drive, if OS X is fixing it in the background, or what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the total size of the disk I suppose you are hit by the 2.2 TB limit of MBR partition tables.

> Since block addresses and sizes are stored in the partition table of an MBR using 32 bits, the maximum size as well as the highest start address of a partition using drives that have 512-byte sectors (actual or emulated) cannot exceed 2 TiB−512 bytes (2,199,023,255,040 bytes or 4,294,967,295 (2^32−1) sectors × 512 (2^9) bytes per sector). Alleviating this capacity limitation was one of the prime motivations for the development of the GPT.

So repartition the disk with a GPT partition table.